# What are the valid Configure signatures in Startup?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How are the valid parameters for `Configure` determined in the `Startup` class? Does anyone know where the documentation is for the acceptable parameters is?

For instance, both of the following are valid:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
```

Answer (score 13):

The startup methods `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` are called by convention and the passed parameters are determined at runtime, so there is no *fixed* signature to implement (unless explicitly implementing [`IStartup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.istartup)).

The `ConfigureServices` method allows only a single parameter: `IServiceCollection`. The method can have that argument or none at all. All other signatures will cause an `InvalidOperationException` when the application starts.

The `Configure` method is a lot more flexible. Apart from the actual `IApplicationBuilder`, which is required to set up the application’s middleware pipeline, you can add *any* parameter you want to it. The arguments will then be evaluated at runtime and resolved *from dependency injection*.

So you can pass *any* dependency that is registered in the service collection and as such can be resolved using dependency injection.

This is also documented in the [application startup documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup#the-configure-method):

> Additional services, like `IHostingEnvironment` and `ILoggerFactory` may also be specified in the method signature, in which case these services will be [injected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) if they are available.

Comment: Great explanation along with links I could not find.  Thanks @poke.